# Cannot flip image over x axes

Tags: rust, ggez

I am using `ggez` rust crate, trying to develop 2d game. Currently I have a problem, where I want to flip image over x axes. So for example if character is looking in right direction, it would look left after transformation. Could not find anything useful in documentation. As I see `DrawParam` struct does not support this. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Image`](https://docs.rs/ggez/latest/ggez/graphics/type.Image.html) struct has a method `draw` in where you can pass some [`DrawParams`](https://docs.rs/ggez/latest/ggez/graphics/struct.DrawParam.html#). `DrawParams` can set [`scaled`](https://docs.rs/ggez/latest/ggez/graphics/struct.DrawParam.html#method.scale) or [`transformed`](https://docs.rs/ggez/latest/ggez/graphics/struct.DrawParam.html#method.transform) which you could use for that.

You would just need to scale by a negative factor, something like:

```rust
image.draw(ctx, draw_params.scale(Vector2::from_slice(&[-1f32, 1f32])));
```

Comment: Did not know scale could be used like that. It solves my problem. Thanks a lot.